# In MIXED models for RM, is it necessary to include interaction effects between covariates and time?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, repeated-measures, longitudinal-data-analysis

I am currently analysing data of a cohort study where we try to model change in a dependent variable (say, academic grades) over three time-points based on a number of continuous independent variables.

The change in grades occurs due to a single intervention between time point 1 and 2 (say, tutoring). Hence, grades increase between TP1 to TP2 and then remain stable to TP3. Independent variables are related to the intervention: weekly hours of tutoring; relationship with the tutor; satisfaction / engagement with the tutoring program.

Due to a substantial amount of missing data at outcomes and for predictors variables, I am planning to use a linear MIXED model, entering grades as DV and the predictors as covariates in SPSS.

**Now where I am uncertain:** In order to interpret the effect of the predictor variables on change (of grades), is it sufficient to include the main effects of time and predictors (as covariates) in the fixed part, OR is it necessary to look at the interactions between time and the respective predictors?

My understanding is that the main effects can only be interpreted as influencing the outcome **across time points**,so if there was a main effect of satisfaction on grades, this could also just mean that people who are satisfied with their tutoring already have high grades at TP1, is that correct?

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to examine the relationship of a covariate to change in grades, you need to include the interaction with time. Otherwise, you are just looking at whether that covariate is related to overall level of grades. However, for "satisfaction with the tutoring program" you will have a problem because kids who didn't get tutored will not have data for that. (OTOH, if all kids got tutored, then you lack a control group, which is another problem).

For your second question, you can have a significant (and important) interaction with time even if you don't have a main effect. In this particular case, this seems possible as students whose grades improved seem likely to be more satisfied with the tutoring program.

You use the word "effect" but that is dangerous. This is (I think) an observational study, so you can't infer causation. And, for the relationships of satisfaction and change in grades, any causation might go in the other direction. Or both directions.